# Sampling from/near boundary of a region in R^n

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, geometry

Suppose $\Omega$ is a region in $\mathbb R^n$, and suppose we are given a function $\chi(x)$ with $\chi(x)=1$ if $x\in \Omega$ and $\chi(x)=0$ otherwise. If it helps we can assume $\Omega\subseteq B$ for some compact box $B$ and that we know two points $x_0\in\Omega$ and $y_0\in\mathbb R^n\backslash\Omega$.

**Assuming we can evaluate $\chi(\cdot)$ inexpensively, does there exist a procedure for sampling points on or near the boundary $\partial\Omega$?**

I have in mind MCMC/Metropolis-Hastings procedures that target distributions that concentrate around $\partial\Omega.$ I can think of a few that might work but before formulating my own method thought I’d make sure this isn’t some classical problem I’m neglecting. It’s probably optimistic to expect to sample eg from the uniform distribution on $\partial\Omega$ since we don’t have a parameterization of this set or means of finding points there, but it’d be great if we could sample from some distribution $p_\alpha$ that concentrates on $\partial\Omega$ as $\alpha\to\infty$.

I don’t want to assume we know something like the distance to $\partial\Omega$, just the indicator function.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a polytope given by $Ax =b, x>=0$- or more generally if you can decompose the boundary into a union of a small number of convex sets - there is something you can do. In particular, you can estimate the area of each boundary piece, and use that to sample the component. Within the component, you can sample approximately uniformly at random. All of this can be done in polynomial time using the ball walk Markov chain in the interior of a convex set. You can use the same method to sample from log concave functions on the interior, but ...

Comment: ... log concave score functions will cause drift towards the interior of the body. Maybe you can expect your convex shape to have most of it's mass near the boundary anyway, because of concentration of measure type phenomenon?

Comment: So, $\chi(x)$ is some black box function taking the values $\{0,1\}$ and you need to (a) discover where this transition happens and (b) sample points near that transition?

Comment: Yes --- preferably with the uniform (Hausdorff) measure